# How do I pivot a table using pyspark without using agregations and creating new columns?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, pivot, pivot-table, multiple-columns

I've got a simple table in spark and I wanted to just pivot the information grouped by ID. So in the final table I'd have 3 new columns for each phone number the customer has.

This is the **original** table:

[original table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PdjpW.png)

This would be the result:

[final table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EaDRC.png)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the required result by unpivoting the data first and then pivoting the fields. Unpivoting can be one using an array-struct explosion.

Here's an example based on your provided sample input.

```py
data_sdf. \
    withColumn('seq', func.row_number().over(wd.partitionBy('id').orderBy(func.lit(1)))). \
    withColumn('unpivot_col', 
               func.array(*[func.struct(func.lit(k).alias('key'), func.col(k).alias('val')) 
                            for k in data_sdf.columns if k != 'id']
                          )
               ). \
    selectExpr('id', 'seq', 'inline(unpivot_col)'). \
    withColumn('pivot_col', func.concat_ws('_', 'key', 'seq')). \
    groupBy('id'). \
    pivot('pivot_col'). \
    agg(func.first('val')). \
    show()

# +------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+---------+
# |    id|nr_ddd_1|nr_ddd_2|nr_ddi_1|nr_ddi_2|nr_tel_1| nr_tel_2|
# +------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+---------+
# |434555|      11|      11|      44|      44|48177778|958039794|
# +------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+---------+
```

The `unpivot_col` column is an array of structs containing the column name (as `key`) and column value (as `val`). The SQL `inline` function explodes the array of structs and creates new columns using the struct fields (in this case, `key` and `val`). As there are multiple entries per id-field, a `row_number` can be used to differentiate them with some sequence.

Once pivoted, you can sort the resulting dataframe's columns. Let's say the aforementioned result is stored in `res_sdf`.

```py
cols_to_sort = filter(lambda x: x != 'id', res_sdf.columns)

# sort based on the sequence assigned at the end
sorted_cols = sorted(cols_to_sort, key=lambda k: '_'.join([k.split('_')[-1]]+k.split('_')[0:-1]))

print(sorted_cols)
# ['nr_ddd_1', 'nr_ddi_1', 'nr_tel_1', 'nr_ddd_2', 'nr_ddi_2', 'nr_tel_2']

# use `sorted_cols` list to select
res_sdf = res_sdf.select('id', *sorted_cols)
```